# How do I set up a firmware password on a MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, security, macbook-pro

I'm trying to follow the instructions for [how to set up a firmware password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1352), the problem is that they don't mention anything about Mac OS X 10.6.*, nor do they mention what to do with a MacBook Air, which doesn't come with an OS X DVD.

If I try searching for "firmware" in spotlight, it doesn't find any relevant application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacBook Air should have come with a bootable USB flash drive for OS reinstalls. Use that and follow the same steps as 10.5.x.

Comment: The USB flash drive contains only two files: Install Mac OS X, and Install iLife. When I try to "show the package contents" of the first file, I see a Content folder, and there doesn't seem to be any files called Firmware utility. If I try launching the installer, it says "To set up the installation of Mac OS X Snow Leopard, click Restart."

Comment: I chose to restart the system and then I was able to access the utility from the menu on top. Thanks for the answer.